# How to check is any music played on computer using winapi?

Tags: winapi

I would like to know is there any music played on this computer. I think about music ( of course I think about any voices, so movie is ok too ) playing in my browser ( for example youtube ), apps like vlc player, music played using code and all other ways to play music.

I know that I can change volume, so maybe there is a way to check music?

Comment: This is not as simple as you'd think. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/coreaudio/peak-meters) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know is there any music played on this computer.

When a client initializes an audio stream, it assigns the audio stream to an **audio session**.

So you may achieve this via monitor audio session.

An audio session contains either rendering streams or capture streams, but not both. So need to distinguish **stream direction**.

The **state** is active if the session has one or more streams that are running. The state changes from active to inactive when the last running stream in the session stops. The session state changes to expired when the client destroys the last stream in the session by releasing all references to the stream object.

Use `IsSystemSoundsSession` method determine whether the session is a **system sounds session**. (instead of user app's audio session).

If an application wants to be notified when new sessions are created, it must register its implementation of [`IAudioSessionNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionenumerator#remarks) with the session manager.

The following is a simple example of using pulling method to enumerate all available sessions and check each state to determine if it is playing audio or not. You can refer to for getting started.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <audiopolicy.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>

#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
              if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }

HRESULT CreateSessionManager(IAudioSessionManager2** ppSessionManager)
{

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
    IAudioSessionManager2* pSessionManager = NULL;

    CoInitialize(0);

    // Create the device enumerator.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),
        NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
        __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
        (void**)&pEnumerator);

    // Get the default audio device.
    hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
        eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);

    // Get the session manager.
    hr = pDevice->Activate(
        __uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL,
        NULL, (void**)&pSessionManager);

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    *(ppSessionManager) = pSessionManager;
    (*ppSessionManager)->AddRef();

done:

    // Clean up.
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSessionManager);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT EnumSessions(IAudioSessionManager2* pSessionManager)
{
    if (!pSessionManager)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    int cbSessionCount = 0;
    LPWSTR pswSession = NULL;

    IAudioSessionEnumerator* pSessionList = NULL;
    IAudioSessionControl* pSessionControl = NULL;
    IAudioSessionControl2* pSessionControl2 = NULL;

    // Get the current list of sessions.
    hr = pSessionManager->GetSessionEnumerator(&pSessionList);

    // Get the session count.
    hr = pSessionList->GetCount(&cbSessionCount);
    wprintf_s(L"Session count: %d\n", cbSessionCount);

    for (int index = 0; index < cbSessionCount; index++)
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(pswSession);
        SAFE_RELEASE(pSessionControl);

        // Get the <n>th session.
        hr = pSessionList->GetSession(index, &pSessionControl);

        hr = pSessionControl->QueryInterface(
            __uuidof(IAudioSessionControl2), (void**)&pSessionControl2);

        hr = pSessionControl2->IsSystemSoundsSession();
        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            wprintf_s(L" this is a system sound.\n");
            continue;
        }
        hr = pSessionControl->GetDisplayName(&pswSession);
        wprintf_s(L"Session Name: %s\n", pswSession);
        AudioSessionState state;
        hr = pSessionControl->GetState(&state);
        switch (state)
        {
        case AudioSessionStateInactive:
            wprintf_s(L"Session state: Inactive\n", state);
            break;
        case AudioSessionStateActive:
            wprintf_s(L"Session state: Active\n", state);
            break;
        case AudioSessionStateExpired:
            wprintf_s(L"Session state: Expired\n", state);
            break;
        }
    }

done:
    CoTaskMemFree(pswSession);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSessionControl);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSessionList);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSessionControl2);
    return hr;

}

int main()
{
    IAudioSessionManager2 *sm = NULL;

    while (true)
    {
        CreateSessionManager(&sm);
        EnumSessions(sm);
        printf("press enter to start new enumation \n");
        getchar();
    }

}
```

More references: [Audio Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-sessions), [Audio Session Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-session-events), [IAudioSessionEnumerator interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionenumerator#remarks), [IAudioSessionManager2 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager2).